# where can I find the 32-bit libraries needed to run MPLAB X?

Tags: kali-linux, libraries

I'm trying to install MPLAB X onto my kali Linux 64-bit OS and every time I get to the last part of installation I receive this message:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# sudo chmod 755 mla_v2014_07_22_linux_installer.run
root@kali:~/Desktop# sudo ./MPLABX-v2.20-linux-installer.sh
  64 Bit, check libraries
  Check for 32 Bit libraries
  These 32 bit libraries were not found and are needed for MPLAB X to run:
   libc.so
   libdl.so
   libgcc_s.so
   libm.so
   libpthread.so
   librt.so
   libstdc++.so
   libexpat.so
   libX11.so
   libXext.so
```

When I enter this command I get this message:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libx11-6:i386 \
     libxext6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libexpat1:i386

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6
E: Unable to locate package libx11-6
E: Unable to locate package libxext6
E: Unable to locate package libstdc++6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++6'
E: Unable to locate package libexpat1
```

How do I find these libraries?

right now it's killing me, It shouldn't be this complicated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Kali, so my answer is for vanilla Debian systems. I hope it is more or less the same for you. In order to install packages from foreign architectures, you have to enable the new architecture with the command

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then you update the lists of packages:

```
apt-get update
```

And then you should be able to install multiarch packages if your distribution supports them (using the command you wrote).

You may also have to check that the `sources.list` files are not specific for one architecture (and I do not expect them to be if you used defaults). For more information (again, in Debian case) see https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since the question is asked, but to help others:

1. make sure the `i368`architecture is enabled as the "foreign architecture" on your host architecture by issueing `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`
2. if it is not enabled, enable it by `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` command
3. run `sudo apt update`
4. install the missing package e.g `sudo apt install libc6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libexpat1:i386`

You may also visit webpages below:

https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:installation
https://microchipdeveloper.com/install:mplabx-lin64